# python itertools groupby return tuple

Tags: python, tuples, python-itertools

I need to parse the flatten structure and create nested structure using the list of keys provided. I have solved the problem but I am looking for an improvement and I would like to learn what I can change in my code. Can somebody review it and refactor using better knowledge?

```
src_data = [
  {
    "key1": "XX",
    "key2": "X111",
    "key3": "1aa",
    "key4": 1
  },
  {
    "key1": "YY",
    "key2": "Y111",
    "key3": "1bb",
    "key4": 11
  },
  {
    "key1": "ZZ",
    "key2": "Z111",
    "key3": "1cc",
    "key4": 2.4
  },
  {
    "key1": "AA",
    "key2": "A111",
    "key3": "1cc",
    "key4": 33333.2122
  },
  {
    "key1": "BB",
    "key2": "B111",
    "key3": "1bb",
    "key4": 2
  },
]
```

this is my code I developed so far creating the final result.

```
def plant_tree(ll):
    master_tree = {}

    for i in ll:
        tree = master_tree
        for n in i:
            if n not in tree:
                tree[n] = {}
            tree = tree[n]
    return master_tree



def make_nested_object(tt, var):
    elo = lambda l: reduce(lambda x, y: {y: x}, l[::-1], var)
    return {'n_path': tt, 'n_structure': elo(tt)}



def getFromDict(dataDict, mapList):
    return reduce(operator.getitem, mapList, dataDict)


def set_nested_item(dataDict, mapList, val):
    """Set item in nested dictionary"""
    reduce(getitem, mapList[:-1], dataDict)[mapList[-1]] = val
    return dataDict



def update_tree(data_tree):
    # MAKE NESTED OBJECT
    out = (make_nested_object(k, v) for k,v, in res_out.items())


    for dd in out:
        leaf_data = dd['n_structure']
        leaf_path = dd['n_path']
        data_tree = set_nested_item(data_tree, leaf_path, getFromDict(leaf_data, leaf_path))
    return data_tree
```

this is the customed itemgeter function from this question

```
def customed_itemgetter(*args):
    # this handles the case when one key is provided
    f = itemgetter(*args)
    if len(args) > 2:
        return f
    return lambda obj: (f(obj),)
```

define the nesting level

```
nesting_keys = ['key1', 'key3', 'key2']

grouper = customed_itemgetter(*nesting_keys)
ii = groupby(sorted(src_data, key=grouper), grouper)

res_out = {key: [{k:v for k,v in i.items() if k not in nesting_keys} for i in group] for key,group in ii}
#
ll = ([dd[x] for x in nesting_keys] for dd in src_data)
data_tree = plant_tree(ll)
```

get results

```
result = update_tree(data_tree)
```

How can I improve my code?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: `<itertools._grouper at 0x7f82d9eb5e48>` is a generator expression, that doesn't tell me anything Please add how do you want your final output after the groupby expression to look like

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh OP's question is about the first element of each tuple, not about the groupers.

Comment: Also `for model, group in groupby(src_data, key=grouper):
    print(model, list(group))` gives me `1 [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'z': 3}]
2 [{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'e': 2}]
4 [{'a': 4, 'x': 3, 'b': 3}]` and not what you mention in the question

Comment: So in reality the dictionary is `{1: {2 : [...]}}` for the sample input? Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Do not edit the question to [invalidate existing answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290704/3956566).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the [**`itemgetter`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) is given a single element, it returns that single element, and does *not* wrap it in a singleton-tuple.

We can however construct a function for that, like:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def itemgetter2(*args):
    f = itemgetter(*args)
    if len(args) > 2:
        return f
    return lambda obj: (f(obj),)
```

then we can thus use the new `itemgetter2`, like:

```
grouper = itemgetter2(*ll)
ii = groupby(sorted(src_data, key=grouper), grouper)
```

**EDIT**: Based on your question however, you want to perform multilevel grouping, we can make a function for that, like:

```
def multigroup(groups, iterable, index=0):
    if len(groups) <= index:
        return list(iterable)
    else:
        f = itemgetter(groups[index])
        i1 = index + 1
        return {
            k: multigroup(groups, vs, index=i1)
            for k, vs in groupby(sorted(iterable, key=f), f)
        }
```

For the `data_src` in the question, this then generates:

```
>>> multigroup(['a', 'b'], src_data)
{1: {2: [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'z': 3}]}, 2: {3: [{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'e': 2}]}, 4: {3: [{'a': 4, 'x': 3, 'b': 3}]}}
```

You can post-process the values in the `list(..)` call however. We can for example generate dictionaries without the elements in the grouping columns:

```
def multigroup(groups, iterable):
    group_set = set(groups)
    fs = [itemgetter(group) for group in groups]
    def mg(iterable, index=0):
        if len(groups) <= index:
            return [
                {k: v for k, v in item.items() if k not in group_set}
                for item in iterable
            ]
        else:
            i1 = index + 1
            return {
                k: mg(vs, index=i1)
                for k, vs in groupby(sorted(iterable, key=fs[index]), fs[index])
            }
    return mg(iterable)
```

For the given sample input, we get:

```
>>> multigroup(['a', 'b'], src_data)
{1: {2: [{'z': 3}]}, 2: {3: [{'e': 2}]}, 4: {3: [{'x': 3}]}}
```

or for the new sample data:

```
>>> pprint(multigroup(['key1', 'key3', 'key2'], src_data))
{'AA': {'1cc': {'A111': [{'key4': 33333.2122}]}},
 'BB': {'1bb': {'B111': [{'key4': 2}]}},
 'XX': {'1aa': {'X111': [{'key4': 1}]}},
 'YY': {'1bb': {'Y111': [{'key4': 11}]}},
 'ZZ': {'1cc': {'Z111': [{'key4': 2.4}]}}}
```

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: no! If `itemgetter(*args)(x)` for example returns something iterable (like a 2-character string), it will spread this over the elements of the tuple. For example `tuple('ab')` is `('a', 'b')`, whereas `('ab', )` remains `('ab', )`.

Comment: Ahh damn, my mistake! +1

Comment: @naivepredictor: is the `multigroup` in the edit more or less what you are looking for?

Comment: @naivepredictor: the second edit, normally should "strip" these keys from the dictionaries.

Comment: @naivepredictor: what if another dictionary has a `'key 3'`, then it is a bit "strange" as in `{'key1: 'a', 'key2': 'b', 'key3': 'c'}, {'key1': 'a', 'key3': 'c'}`. The problem is that the result should be something of the shape `{ 'a': ... }`, but what do you suggest as value for `'a'`? A dictionary? Then how do we insert a dictionary without a key in that? A list? Then how do we add subcategories?